# Deprecate the web tab in Salesforce Account

Tags: visualforce

I created the VisualForce page tab it is working fine but the s-control tab is also showing in the UI so , I want to deprecate that s-control tab . Please any one can help me

EDIT: Yes, I want to delete/remove that s-control tab

I have even done this -- Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles -> Select Your Profile -> Edit -> Tab Settings, but the tab is still appearing.

Comment: Deprecate or remove? Deprecation generally means that the functionality still works, but shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions for this problem.

1. You can remove this tab from the app

   - Setup -> Create -> App -> Select Your App -> Remove the tab from the `Selected Tabs`
2. Hide this tab for certain profiles

   - Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles -> Select Your Profile -> Edit -> Tab Settings